# Notification Service Extension integration with Flavor in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, unnotificationserviceextension

I have a flutter project with the following flavors.

```
1. Develop
2. Stage
3. Production
```

**flutter doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Now, I have to integrate `Notification Service Extension` on the iOS side of the flutter project.

While running the project from VS Code, with `flavor` as `develop` I am getting the following error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: **********
Xcode build done.                                           25.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'connectivity' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'audioplayers' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'camera' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'video_player' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'qr_code_scanner' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'permission_handler' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'location_permissions' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'local_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'image_cropper' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'geolocator' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'flutter_image_compress' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'flutter_audio_recorder' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'SDWebImageWebPCoder' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'SDWebImage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Mantle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

And running the app from Xcode, I get the following error.

```
Ld /Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Products/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos/notificationserviceextension.appex/notificationserviceextension normal (in target 'notificationserviceextension' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/sunflowermacmini/Documents/Sagar/Work/ResolvedX/resolved-flutter/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios10.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk -L/Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Products/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos -F/Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Products/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos -filelist /Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos/notificationserviceextension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/notificationserviceextension.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos/notificationserviceextension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/notificationserviceextension_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fapplication-extension -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos/notificationserviceextension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/notificationserviceextension.swiftmodule -framework Flutter -e _NSExtensionMain -framework Pods_Runner -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos/notificationserviceextension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/notificationserviceextension_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/sunflowermacmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpmgvahwyempvlfdmdfmsrvejyhh/Build/Products/Debug\ -\ develop-iphoneos/notificationserviceextension.appex/notificationserviceextension

ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

NOTE: I have tried changing the **IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET** of every pod to **9.0**. Also took a reference from the this link.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12828